# Cant find the source of the AttributeError I'm getting

Tags: python

I'm learning Python 3. I'm stuck with an exercise. I can't find the issue in the code below that gives me an `AttributeError` message.

```
#child class of Users called Admin
class Admin(Users):
    """Initilize Users parent class attributes"""
    def __init__(self, name, last, year, location):
        super().__init__(name, last, year, location)

        self.admin_privileges = Privileges()


#attribute class to child class Admin
class Privileges():
    """Initilize attributes"""
    def __inti__(self, privileges=[]):
        self.privileges_list = privileges

    def show_privileges(self):
        """Displays admin privileges"""
        print('As an admin you can: ')
        if self.privileges_list:
            for privilege in self.privileges_list:
                print('-' + privilege)
        else:
            print("This account doesn't have privileges.")



admin = Admin('bob', 'chef', '1883', 'usa')
admin.greet_user()
admin.describe_user()
admin_priv = ['can add posts', 'can delete post', 'can ban user']
admin.admin_privileges.privileges = admin_priv
admin.admin_privileges.show_privileges()
```

Here's the output which shows the error:

```
User Bob's information:
First name: Bob
Last name: Chef
Birth year: 1883
Location: Usa
Login's: 0
As an admin you can:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "user_class.py", line 84, in <module>
    admin.admin_privileges.show_privileges()
  File "user_class.py", line 71, in show_privileges
    if self.privileges_list:
AttributeError: 'Privileges' object has no attribute 'privileges_list'
```

I have tried looking for the answer but can't find anything. I'm sure that I forgot something.

Comment: `__inti__` is not `__init__`.